# How to handle expand button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Attaching the screenshot for the application, I am not able to find the logic/xpath to click on expand button.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `//div[@class='x-grid3-row-expander']`?

Comment: What about the div that contains the button? Did you try to click it?

Comment: @MateMrše Its giving 14 elements on the page. I tried //td/div[@class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-expander"]/div[@class='x-grid3-row-expander'] , but not working

Comment: @Jonah Yes but its giving 14 elements on the page and I am not able to find out find out the uniqueness for the xpath, I tried multiple permutation and combination.

Comment: Do you need to click on all 14 elements?

Comment: If you get 14 elements, then you can choose by index (if you just want to expand first entry), or make an xpath that will expand by the id of the entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on any specific `+` then use the below.

```
# let's say you want to click on the 4th `+` icon then pass the number 4 in the index as shown below
(//td/div[@class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-expander"]/div[@class='x-grid3-row-expander'])[4]
```